# c reference semantic isn't explicit in caller's code

Tags: c++, c

Can anybody explain this?

> Old line C programmers sometimes don't like references since they provide reference semantics that isn't explicit in the caller's code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use a C++ function like:

```
void make42 (int &x) { x = 42; }
```

and call it thus:

```
int y = 7;
make42 (y); // y is now 42
```

then there is *no* indication in the `make42 (y)` call that `y` can be changed. Exactly the same function call would be made if it *wasn't* a pass-by-reference parameter:

```
void trymake42 (int x) { x = 42; }

int y = 7;
trymake42 (y); // y is still 7
```

In C code, it would be something like:

```
void make42 (int *px) {
    *px = 42;
}
int y = 7;
make42 (&y);
```

making it clear that a change to `y` is a real possibility when calling the function.

So what these "old line" C coders would be concerned about is a line like:

```
someFunction (x);
```

where they would have no idea from *just* that whether `x` would change or not.

I have to say that, as one of these old line coders, it's far less of a problem than the quote seems to imply. Without seeing the prototype, I can't even tell what the parameter types should be, or how many there are, or their order.

So, having to refer to said prototype to figure out if a parameter is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference is not really an big deal.

C# takes a different tack with the `out` and `ref` parameter modifiers but that still makes it explicit in the call whether the variable is pass-by-value or pass-by-reference.

Comment: " as one of these old line coders, it's far less of a problem than the quote seems to imply" -- same here. If I pass a `char*` to a function, will the function modify the string? It depends on function. Even in C#, if you invoke a method on an object or pass an object reference as an argument, you don't know whether the method will change the object. What's so special about changing the value of an argument that it needs call site syntax?